# The DateandTime, regarding seconds

Tags: c#, datetime, timer

Hello Guyz i have this small problem regard the DateandTime this is my Code

```
labelDateAndTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy,MM hh:mm:ss tt");
```

my problem here is that the time is not moving(changing). but it gets the right and exact time
whenever i run my program

Comment: You mean seconds are not changing

Comment: yes that was exactly my problem

Comment: Are you running this in a loop or with a timer ?

Comment: Use a windows forms `Timer` to set the text.

Comment: of course it will not move unless you do a refresh try to use an update panel control and place the label inside it check this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx

Comment: Is your example in ASP.NET / WinForms / WPF?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the refreshing. You can add a timer to your app and on timer tick event you can refresh the text in you label. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a loop for refresh your Datetime every seconds.

For sample.

```
while(true)
{
    labelDateAndTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy,MM hh:mm:ss tt");
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep one second.
}
```

call this loop in asynchronous for not stopping your program.

You can also create a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):

```
    refreshTimer = new Timer(10000);

    refreshTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(YourTimerFunction);

    private void YourTimerFunction()
    {
        labelDateAndTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy,MM hh:mm:ss tt");
    }
```

Two method works, but Timer is better is more accurate.

Comment: A `Timer` is a *much* better solution. This one costs a whole thread and can change the `Text` while another method is running on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes,I know, I've edit my post for to present the two solutions.

Comment: Timer isn't more accurate, it offers better thread safety and consumes less resources.

Comment: Accessing an UI element from a background thread is not a good idea, most likely it will throw an exception.

Comment: I agree with you for Timer is much better solution. But It's also more acurate than the while loop: If you create a while loop with log the time, (with a thread.sleep every second) and you log the time of a timer. Logs are same if you've just a little program. 

BUT, if your program have many thread an treatment, the While loop become less accurate than the timer. Your While lopp can be called every 1.1 or 1.2 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

That is because DateTime.Now works at the very instant you have called it.

Comment: so what code should i use in order to get the exact time while running my program :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a one time assignment. You convert the current time to a string and assign it to a Label. Of course it won't change, you didn't write code to change it. Look at the various `Timer` classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
 <html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled 1</title>
   <script runat="server" type="text/c#">
   protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Label1.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " +
    DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
   }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
      <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">      </asp:Timer>
  <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Page not refreshed yet." id="Label1">
 </asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label" id="Label2"></asp:Label>
   </form>
  </body>
    </html>
```